# How to make a Python program run when starting my Mac?

Tags: python, macos

I want to have one of my Python programs run when I start my Mac. I would also like the option to specify when I would like other Python programs to run on my Mac. For example, every day at 4pm.

I had done research and I understand that in order to do this, you have to create a Launch Daemon and add it to the Mac LaunchD. I also saw that you have to create a "plist" file that corresponds to your specific Python script.

But, how do I create a plist file? I understand that you have to use a specific template, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>script.name</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/python</string>
        <string>/path/to/python/script.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/python_script.error</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, what application do I use in order to write this? Do I enter this text in an application such as TextEdit, Xcode? And how do I save this file so that my Mac recognizes it as a plist file?

Then, how do I add this plist file into the LaunchD so my scripts can run on startup, or at my specified time?

I know I have a lot of questions, but I couldn't find straight answers on other websites. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To edit this use a text editor, like TextEdit. You have to save it with an extension of `.plist` so it looks something like: `myprogramlauncher.plist`.

Then, you move it to one of these directories: `/System/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`, or `/Users/<username>/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Afterward, use `initctl load path/to/myprogramlauncher.plist` (replacing with the location of your file.)

Comment: `/System/Library/Launch*` is reserved for Apple. Use `/Library/Launch*` for admin-provided services

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the future, if I didn't want my Python script running on startup anymore, how would I be able to delete this plist file from the LaunchDaemons? Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to delete files on mac (as i'm on windows) but the unload command is the same as the load command but with `unload` so `initctl unload path/to/myprogramlauncher.plist`